# Optimize matrix to have the least number of rows with NaN

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, missing-data

I have a matrix `M`. Let's assume that each row of the matrix `M` is a subject and each column is a measurement.

```
M=rand(100);                % generate a 100x100 matrix random
c=randperm(length(M),100);  %select randomly 100 measurement indices
r=randperm(length(M),100);  %select randomly 100 subject indices

for i = 1 : 100
    M(r(i),c(i))=NaN;       % add randomly NaN. i.e. the subject c(i) does not have measurement c(i)
end
```

Now I delete the measurements that are missing for all the subjects (if any)

```
idx_col_all_NAN = find(all(isnan(M)==1));   
M(:,idx_col_all_NAN)=[];
```

and I delete the subjects for which all the measurements are missing (if any)

```
idx_row_all_NAN = find(all(isnan(M)==1,2));   
M(idx_row_all_NAN,:)=[];
```

Now I would like to remove the measurements in order to maximize the number of subjects with the same measurements and minimize the cells of `M` containing NaN.

Could you help me?

Comment: so if 2 subjects (A and B) have one measurement with an equal value and A has a NaN somewhere you want that the NaN is replaced by the measurement value of B, is that correct? should every measurement be checked for equality?

Comment: Just for you to know: `isnan(M)` will give you the same result as `isnan(M)==1`.

Comment: @Finn no this is not what I meant... I do not want to replace any value...just find the combination of subjects and measurements that minimize the number of NaN

Comment: so remove all subjects and measurements where there is at least one NaN in the measurement or subject?

Comment: @Finn in principle yes, but with real data I will remove all the subjects :(

Comment: i see so there is quite something missing. How aboud a threshold? like with 5 or more NaN should be removed the rest can stay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to continue removing NaNs from your matrix, you need to have some rule for how to maximize the tradeoff between less data and less NaN. As you said, if you continue to remove NaNs without any limit - you may remain with a very small amount of data. There is no *correct* rule for that, it really depends on what you are asking, the following suggestion is only to give you an idea of how to deal with such a problem.

So as a starting point, I define an index to the 'quality' of the matrix, in terms of how many 'holes' are in it:

```
M_ratio = sum(~isnan(M(:)))/numel(M); % the ratio between numbers to M size
```

This index will be greater as more data is in the matrix, and it equals 1 if there are no NaN. We could continue to remove row/columns from the matrix as long as we see an improvement, but because the matrix is getting smaller as long as there are NaN left we will always see an improvement, so we will left with empty matrix (or a very small one, depends on how much NaNs we had).

So we need to define some threshold for the improvement, such that if the deletion does not improve the matrix in a certain amount - we stop the process:

```
improve = 1-M_old_ratio/M_new_ratio % the relative improvement after deletion
```

`improve` is the relative gain in our 'quality' index, and if it is not big enough we stop deleting row/columns from the matrix. What is big enough? this is hard to say, but I'll leave it to you to play with and see what gives you a decent result.

So here is the full code for that:

```
N = 100;
M = rand(N); % generate a NxN random matrix
M(randi(numel(M),N^2,1)) = nan;  % add NaN to randomly selected N^2 measurements
M(:,all(isnan(M)))=[]; % delete all NaN columns
M(all(isnan(M),2),:)=[]; % delete all NaN rows
threshold = 0.003; % the threshold for stop optimizing the matrix
while 1
    M_ratio = sum(~isnan(M(:)))/numel(M); % the ratio between numbers to M size
    [mincol,indcol] = min(sum(~isnan(M),1)); % find the column with most NaN
    [minrow,indrow] = min(sum(~isnan(M),2)); % find the row with most NaN
    [~,dir] = min([minrow;mincol]); % find which has more NaNs
    Mtry = M;
    if dir == 1
        Mtry(indrow,:) = []; % delete row
    else
        Mtry(:,indcol) = []; % delete column
    end
    Mtry_ratio = sum(~isnan(Mtry(:)))/numel(Mtry); % get the new ratio
    improve = 1-M_ratio/Mtry_ratio; % the relative improvement after deletion
    if improve>threshold % if it improves more than the threshold
        M = Mtry; % replace the matrix
    else
        break; % otherwise - quit
    end
end
```

if you only consider removing columns, and not rows, it's a bit simmpler:

```
threshold = 0.002; % the threshold for stop optimizing the matrix
while 1
    M_ratio = sum(~isnan(M(:)))/numel(M); % the ratio between numbers to M size
    [~,indcol] = min(sum(~isnan(M),1)); % find the column with most NaN
    Mtry = M;
    Mtry(:,indcol) = []; % delete column
    Mtry_ratio = sum(~isnan(Mtry(:)))/numel(Mtry); % get the new ratio
    improve = 1-M_ratio/Mtry_ratio; % the relative improvement after deletion
    if improve>threshold % if it improves more than the threshold
        M = Mtry; % replace the matrix
    else
        break; % otherwise - quit
    end
end
```

As you will notice I introduced NaN to the matrix in a more compact way, but it doesn't matter, since you have a real data. Also I use logical indexing, which is more compact and efficient way to remove columns and rows.

Comment: thanks for the answer! 
If the matrix M is not a square matrix would this be a bias? What I mean is that for example it will most likely delete rows if there are more columns than rows..

Comment: @gabboshow It depends on what you consider as bias. What it counts is the number of `nan`, and it tries to maximize the data/cells ratio in all the table. It will delete the row/column that will bring the best result. If it will be a row or a column really depends on how the `nan` are distributed in your matrix. Again, the method above is only a 'way-of-thinking' suggestion, you must start from your question about the data, and from that infer what will be the best way to treat missing values. Maybe you don't need to remove them at all...